How can I stop smelly air coming in thru my bathroom exhaust fan?
My stupid apartment building was constructed so that the bathroom fans blow into neighboring apartments. The manager is lazy and cheap and refuses to do anything, but when the neighbor's fan is on my bathroom stinks like tobacco from old smoke residue in the walls and I'm sick of it.
If I buy this "backdraft damper" https://www.temu.com/1pc-bathroom-ventilation-valve-universal-exhaust-fan-check-valve-for-110-pipes-plastic-anti-backflow-valve-for-toilet-exhaust-with-inclined-gravity-design-and-spring-buckle-closure-g-601099557109767.html
and duct tape it on the side of a cardboard box with the sides and bottom sealed and then tape the box onto the ceiling so it covers the bathroom fan, would that be effective in stopping air from other people's bathrooms from entering my apartment thru the fan?
Do those dampers work in any orientation or do they need to be horizontal? I could tape it over the fan without a box if it works vertically.
Any better suggestions?
thanks

If you let your fan run 24/7 might work. It consumes about same as a 100 watt light bulb.

The smell comes from multiple neighbors. Leaving the fan on seems to reduce or stop the smell from one but increases the other.

It seems you're prepared to tape stuff to your ceiling,  you could make a check valve from plastic sheets and cardboard.  It's just a flap that opens when the fan sucks on it, and closes when it stops.
